# SSRS lookup function not fetching data in correct

Tags: reporting-services

> Table1:

```
+------------+
| Id  Value1 |
+------------+
| 1  abc     |
| 1  bda     |
| 1  bvc     |
+------------+
```

> Table2:

```
+-----------+
| ID Value2 |
+-----------+
| 1  11     |
| 1  12     |
| 1  13     |
+-----------+
```

Now I have used Lookup function in ssrs(Below)

```
=Lookup(Field!ID.Value,Field!ID.Value,Field!Value2.Value,"Table2")
```

And the result looks like this:

```
+------------------+
| ID Value1 Value2 |
+------------------+
| 1  abc  11       |
| 1  bda  11       |
| 1  bvc  11       |
+------------------+
```

Field name `Value2` values are not fetching correct.

Please help on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If your two tables are from the same data source, and you're able to adjust the SQL query, it's much easier to `JOIN` the tables into a single dataset instead of using `Lookup()` expressions.

`Lookup()` will only return the first value with a matching ID. As all your IDs are the same, `Lookup()` is just returning the first value in Table2 for all rows.

If you only want to look up one specific row from Table2, you'll need to find a unique ID number (primary key) that can be referenced in Table2. If you want to look up ALL the rows that match between Table1 and Table2, you'll need to use `LookupSet()` instead.

There's likely some options to Lookup by each table's Row Number, but you might want to reassess your data structure and/or report design before considering this.